# Angular Datatables Not Applying Correctly

Tags: angularjs, datatables

Here is my html code:

```
<div ng-controller="withAjaxCtrl">
   <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {

var manageBackOrdersController = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $http({
        url: '/Profiles/firstJson',
        method: "GET",
        params: {}
    }).success(function (data) {
        var JSON = data;
        $scope.data = JSON;

    });

} 

manageBackOrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams'];

angular.module('customersApp')
  .controller('manageOrdersController', manageOrdersController);

angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables'])
    .controller('withAjaxCtrl', function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('scope.data')
           .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Customer').withTitle('Customer')
        ];
    });

}());
```

When I run my page I get an error saying "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'withAjaxCtrl' is not a function, got undefined". My data is found stored in $scope.data.

Answer (score 6):

Respectfully, Sameer's answer is incorrect. It took me two long arduoous days but I found the solution.

What you must keep in mind are 2 concerns:

1. Use DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise, and
2. Have your promise inside your factory.

**This is the correct solution:**

> ```
> 'use strict';
>  WithResponsiveCtrl.$inject = ['DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', 'simpleFactory'];
>  angular.module('showcase.withResponsive', [])
> .controller('WithResponsiveCtrl', WithResponsiveCtrl);
>
> function WithResponsiveCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, simpleFactory) {
> var vm = this;
> vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
>     return simpleFactory.getData(); }).withPaginationType('full_numbers')
>     // Active Responsive plugin
>     .withOption('responsive', true);
> vm.dtColumns = [
>     DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
>     DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
>     // .notVisible() does not work in this case. Use .withClass('none') instead
>     DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').withClass('none')
> ]; }
> ```

---

> ```
> simpleFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q', '$log'];
> angular.module('showcase.withResponsive').factory('simpleFactory', simpleFactory); 
> function simpleFactory($http, $q, $log) {
> return {
>     getData: function () {
>         var deferred = $q.defer();
>         $http.get('api/data.json')
>             .success(function (data) {
>                 deferred.resolve(data);
>             }).error(function (msg, code) {
>                 deferred.reject(msg);
>                 $log.error(msg, code);
>             });
>         return deferred.promise;
>     }
> } };
> ```

Comment: thanks for the update @user1177440 , that answer was just given on the top of my head that time, thus mentioned 'try replacing', anyways I will remove my answer and upvote yours, keep up the good work

Comment: Oh I tried deleting it, it says I cant delete an accepted answer